# Passing an XmlElement to a background job in powershell

Tags: powershell

I've read that objects are serialized when you pass them into a script block called with `start-job`. This seems to work fine for strings and things, but I'm trying to pass an `xml.XmlElement` object in. I'm sure that the object is an `XMLElement` before I invoke the script block, but in the job, I get this error:

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'node'. Cannot convert the "[xml.XmlElement]System.Xml.XmlElement"
value of type "System.String" to type "System.Xml.XmlElement".
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

So, how do I get my `XmlElement` back. Any ideas?

For what it's worth, this is my code:

```
$job = start-job -Name $node.LocalName -InitializationScript $DEFS -ScriptBlock {
    param (
        [xml.XmlElement]$node,
        [string]$folder,
        [string]$server,
        [string]$user,
        [string]$pass
    )
    sleep -s $node.startTime
    run-action $node $folder $server $user $pass
} -ArgumentList $node, $folder, $server, $user, $pass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you can't pass XML nodes into script blocks because you can't serialize them. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17312587/1630171) you need to wrap the node into a new XML document object and pass that into the script block. Thus something like this might work:

```
$wrapper = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument  
$wrapper.AppendChild($wrapper.ImportNode($node, $true)) | Out-Null

$job = Start-Job -Name $node.LocalName -InitializationScript $DEFS -ScriptBlock {
  param (
    [xml]$xml,
    [string]$folder,
    [string]$server,
    [string]$user,
    [string]$pass
  )
  $node = $xml.SelectSingleNode('/*')
  sleep -s $node.startTime
  run-action $node $folder $server $user $pass
} -ArgumentList $wrapper, $folder, $server, $user, $pass
```