# foreach loop when using Xml.XmlElement in remote scriptblock

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm passing an `XmlElement` to a function which in turn is pass that `XmlElement` into a scriptblock for remote execution. What's occurring is that only some of the elements are getting read via the `foreach` loop. This seems to be regardless if I'm passing the XML with `$using` or passing it as an ArrayList.

The XML section:

```xml
<task>
    <apps>
        <app name="Sample">
            <db name="Basic"/>
            <db name="Interntl"/>
            <db name="Xchgrate"/>
        </app>
        <app name="Vision">
            <db name="Plan1"/>
        </app>
    </apps>
</task>
```

PowerShell code:

```bsh
foreach ($App in $using:task.apps.app) {
  $AppName = $App.name
  foreach ($Db in $App.db) {
    $DbName = $Db.name
    $AppFolder = "$DestinationFolder\$AppName\$DbName"
    $AppFolder
  }
}
```

The resultant output is this if `$DestinationFolder` is set to C:\Staging:

```
C:\Staging\Objects\Applications\Sample\Basic
C:\Staging\Objects\Applications\Sample\Interntl
C:\Staging\Objects\Applications\Sample\Xchgrate
```

I'm confused as to why I don't see Vision app and db entries? It's like it just skips it? What's even more strange is that if I comment out

```xml
<db name="Plan1"/>
```

The output has the Vision app in it.

```
C:\Staging\Objects\Applications\Sample\Basic
C:\Staging\Objects\Applications\Sample\Interntl
C:\Staging\Objects\Applications\Sample\Xchgrate
C:\Staging\Objects\Applications\Vision\
```

Answer (score 0):

The object inside the scriptblock becomes a `Deserialized.System.Xml.XmlElement` object, which apparently behaves slightly different from a regular `System.Xml.XmlElement` object. You can see the object type by running something like this inside the scriptblock:

```
$using:task | Get-Member
```

To avoid this issue create your folder list outside the scriptblock and pass the string array as an argument when invoking the scriptblock on the remote host:

```
$AppFolders = foreach ($App in $task.apps.app) {
  foreach ($Db in $App.db) {
    '{0}\{1}\{2}' -f $DestinationFolder, $App.name, $Db.name
  }
}

Invoke-Command -Computer 'remotehost' -ScriptBlock {
  Param($folders)
  ...
} -ArgumentList (,$AppFolders)
```

The expression `,$AppFolders` is required to avoid unrolling the array. Without it only the first element of the list would be passed to `$folders`.

Answer (score 0):

So according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17312587/1630171) you need to wrap the node into a new XML document object and pass that into the script block. So simply what worked for me was to do this

```
$wrapper = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$wrapper.AppendChild($wrapper.ImportNode($task, $true)) | Out-Null
```

Then pass the $wrapper via -ArgumentList(,$wrapper)

```
$sb = {
 param([object]$wrapper)
 foreach ($App in $wrapper.task.apps.app) {
  $AppName = $App.name
  foreach ($Db in $App.db) {
    $DbName = $Db.name
    $AppFolder = "$DestinationFolder\$AppName\$DbName"
    $AppFolder
  }
 }
}
```

Worked like a charm!!! Thanks for all the help.